# clearRect not clearing anything in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

My code below is for Chris Courses "Circular Motion" tutorial, but I can't figure out why my clearRect isn't working. It's got to be something I'm just not seeing, I have two other canvas animations working now, but this one wont clear the rect and it's driving me nuts....

Thanks for anyone who has the time to help!

```js
function spirals() {
  const canvas2 = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
  canvas2.width = document.getElementById('mycanvas').scrollWidth;
  canvas2.height = document.getElementById('mycanvas').scrollHeight;
  const c2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');

  const spiralColorArray = [
    '#ff0000',
    '#00ff00',
    '#0000ff'
  ];

  addEventListener('resize', () => {
    canvas2.width = document.getElementById('mycanvas').scrollWidth;
    canvas2.height = document.getElementById('mycanvas').scrollHeight;

    init();
  });

  function SpinnerIcon(h, v, radius, color) {
    this.h = h;
    this.v = v;
    this.color = color;
    this.radius = radius;
    
    this.update = () => {
      this.h += 1;
      this.draw();
    };
  
    this.draw = () => {
      c2.beginPath;
      c2.arc(this.h, this.v, this.radius, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
      c2.fillStyle = this.color;
      c2.fill();
      c2.closePath();
    }
  }

  function init() {
    spinnerArray = [];

    for(let i=0; i < 1; i++) {
      spinnerArray.push(new SpinnerIcon(canvas2.width/2, canvas2.height/2, 5, 'red'))
    }
  }
  
  let spinnerArray;

  function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    c2.clearRect(0, 0, canvas2.width, canvas2.height);

    spinnerArray.forEach(parti => {
      parti.update();
    })
  }

  init();
  animate();
}

spirals();
```

```css
#mycanvas {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="mycanvas" width="500" height="500">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your line with `c2.beginPath` is missing () and should be `c2.beginPath();` since it's a function. clearPath won't work when beginPath isn't called.

Comment: I knew it would be something like that. Thanks a lot!